# Enabling curl in php5

Tags: php, unix, curl, macports

I am using macports on my machine and I realized that curl is not enabled. Is there anyway to enable it without completely reconfiguring php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, make sure you have the most recent version of macports by running this:

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
port upgrade outdated
```

According to the macports documentation [here](http://2tbsp.com/content/install_apache_2_and_php_5_macports), the php5 port should include the curl extension by default. You should be able to install it by doing this from terminal:

```
sudo port install php56
```

To install just the curl extension, you can do this:

```
sudo port install php56-curl
```

Comment: note php5-curl has been made obsolete by the port php53-curl. Use

sudo port install php53-curl

instead

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with macports but if you can locate the php.ini file look for the following line.

```
;extension=php_curl.so
```

Change it took

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

This will enable the curl module.

Note: the exact extension name might not be the same.

Comment: instead of .dll it will say .so i believe. you should still have a php.ini file, even on a mac.

Comment: there are no .so lines

i think it needs to be recompiled somehow

Comment: do this after you install the php5-curl package.